# How to add Margin/padding in LinearLayout programmatically?

Tags: android

I am trying to set padding to my linear layouts so that when I press 'create row' they have a gap between them each.

I tried adding `marginTop` and `marginBottom` to my `LinearLayout` but when I run the code, the layout is still spawn in together. not with a gap from the margin I set.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/verticalLayout"
        android:layout_below="@id/button"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        >
```

[image]

(the above image shows 3 linear layouts I added by pressing create row)

Edit: I tried adding a `marginRight` to it, just to see if anything worked on it, and it did.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout verticallayout,horizontalLayout; //got

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        verticallayout = findViewById(R.id.verticalLayout); //got

    }

    public void createRow(View view){

        createRow(); //got

    }



    private void createRow() { //got

        horizontalLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams horizontalParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        horizontalLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        horizontalParams.setMargins(15, 5, 15, 5); // LEFT, TOP, RIGHT, BOTTOM
        horizontalLayout.setLayoutParams(horizontalParams);


        createSpinner();
        createCheckbox();
        createEditText();

        verticallayout.addView(horizontalLayout, horizontalParams);
    }








    private void createEditText() {
        EditText editText = new EditText(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams editParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        editParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);

        editText.setLayoutParams(editParams);
        horizontalLayout.addView(editText);
    }


    private void createCheckbox() { //done
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams checkParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        checkParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        checkParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;

        checkBox.setLayoutParams(checkParams);
        horizontalLayout.addView(checkBox);

    }

    private void createSpinner() {

        Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
        //ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
        //spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams spinnerParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        spinnerParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        spinnerParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;

        spinner.setLayoutParams(spinnerParams);
        horizontalLayout.addView(spinner);
    }
}
```

Comment: add method which you use to add view programmatically.

Comment: Edited in post .

Comment: You are creating a new `LinearLayout`, and not inflating from the xml.

Comment: You aren't adding any margin when you add the views programatically.  You realize that adding a margin on a view puts margin on the view within its parent, right?  So applying a margin to verticalLayout will NOT add margin to its children

Comment: Margin should be added to the child view, and not the parent

Comment: ohh so I should set margins to horizontalParams

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one code

```
    private void createRow() { //got

        horizontalLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams horizontalParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        horizontalLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        horizontalParams.setMargins(15, 5, 15, 5); // LEFT, TOP, RIGHT, BOTTOM
        horizontalLayout.setLayoutParams(horizontalParams);
horizontalLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

        createSpinner();
        createCheckbox();
        createEditText();

        verticallayout.addView(horizontalLayout, horizontalParams);
    }
```

hope so it will be useful for you. :)

Comment: @Magic_Whizz please add createSpinner();
    createCheckbox();
    createEditText(); these function code also

Comment: @Magic_Whizz founded  issue

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: replace *this* with *getContext()*

Comment: check ans again

Comment: @Magic_Whizz try to increase top margin then check use *horizontalParams.setMargins(15, 155, 15, 5);*

Comment: I realise it is actually adding margin padding *inside* the linear layout, instead of outside . https://imgur.com/a/DTThT44

Comment: i want it so there's just a blank white gap between each row/linearlayout

Comment: @Magic_Whizz ok got it for that you have to remove android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" background from your  xml layout then check my Edited Answer

Comment: but I want a colour on the background of each row

Comment: I just want gaps between each row

Comment: yes bro i added code for that in my answer check my answer you will find new line setBackgroundColor

Comment: can't resolve symbol getActivity (). do i put 'this'

Comment: use this instead  of  getActivity()

Answer (score 0):

Add margin to horizontal layout not in Vertical layout. check following code:

```
private void createRow() { 

        horizontalLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams horizontalParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        horizontalParams.topMargin = 20;  //add margin here.

        horizontalLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        horizontalLayout.setLayoutParams(horizontalParams);

        createSpinner();
        createCheckbox();
        createEditText();

        verticallayout.addView(horizontalLayout);
    }
```

Comment: that didn't work either :/  the layouts are still joined together. no space between them

Comment: post new screen shot.